# Visblility of the control in asp.net? using javascript?

Tags: javascript

In asp dot net, i make one button visibility false, and when user enter any text in textbox then the button is   visibility is true. i trying to make this but i am getting error in java script that object is not found. The below is my code.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID ="txt" runat ="server" onkeyup="SetButtonStatus(event,'Button1')" ></asp:TextBox> 


<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" style ="display :none;"     Text="Button" />
```

the scritp:

```
  function SetButtonStatus(evt,btn)
  {
    var vs =document.getElementById("<%= txt.ClientID %>").value;
   if(vs.length >= 1 )
    {   
      if( document.getElementById(btn) == null )  
      {            
           document.getElementById(btn).style.display = "block" ;             

      }                 
    }
    else if(vs.length ==0) 
    {
      document.getElementById(btn).style.display="none";
    }
  }
```

Error i am getting is : Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `Visible ="false"` and then try.

Use only `style="display:none"`

#### Edit-1

Update Your Code this work fine:-

```
<script>
        function SetButtonStatus(evt) {
            var vs = document.getElementById("<%= txt.ClientID %>").value;
            if (vs.length >= 1) {
                if (document.getElementById("<%= Button1.ClientID %>") == null) {
                   //document.getElementById(btn).style.display = "block";
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("<%= Button1.ClientID %>").style.display = "block";
                }
            }
            else if (vs.length == 0) {
                document.getElementById("<%= Button1.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>


 <asp:TextBox ID ="txt" runat ="server" onkeyup="SetButtonStatus(event)" ></asp:TextBox> 
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" style="display:none;" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: I am getting error at : document.getElementById(btn).style.display = "block" ;